# Issue with jQuery deferred and Backbone's success method on save

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, jquery-deferred

So I'm trying to use jQuery's deferred (and the fact that `$.ajax` returns a promise) to handle some asynchronous code.

Here's a quick example which shows what's happening

```
var update_model = function(model, resp){
    model.set('id', resp.id);
    m = model;
};

var print_id = function(){
    console.log(m.get('id'));
};

var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var m = new MyModel({title: 'test'});

var model_promise = m.save({author: 'me'}, {success: update_model});

$.when(model_promise).then(print_id);
```

The problem is that `print_id` is being called BEFORE `update_model` and I'm not sure how to make it happen the other way around.

In the actual example, I'm trying to save anywhere from 1 to 100 models, and I need to get the IDs from those models before I can move onto the next step.

Am I missing something basic here?

---

**EDIT**

`update_model` does get called -- it just happens after `print_id`.  Also, I've tried using the `done` method on `model_promise` and then using `then`:

```
model_promise.done(update_model).then(print_id);
```

But then `update_model` doesn't receive it's necessary arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your deferred resolves in the success method. To use deferreds w/the ajax methods use the the `deferred.done().then()` pattern (check out the "The jqXHR Object" section here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

```
var update_model = function(model, resp){ 
  model.set('id', resp.id); 
  m = model; 
};

var print_id = function(){ 
  console.log(m.get('id')); 
};

var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({}); 
var m = new MyModel({title: 'test'});

var $model_promise = m.save({author: 'me'});

$model_promise.done(update_model).then(print_id);
```

Comment: Just realized this probably doesn't pass the model as the first attr to the success method...

Comment: I've already tried this.  Calling `update_model` via the `.done` method of the promise passes no arguments to the `update_model` method, which are a requirement for this working correctly.

Comment: Also, the `update_model` method actually does get called, but happens after `print_id` gets called.  Updated my initial question.